# How to store a multiple array

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, linked-list

So far, my Java application randomly generates an array.

How could I store this array as a data-structure, to allow me to search for and lookup data in it?

Do linked lists do this? Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'search and lookup'. Does search mean checking if an item is present? Are you intending to lookup using a key?

Answer (score 0):

An array is already a data-structure.

You can easily lookup data in an array. A simple way is:

```
public static boolean exists (String objective, String[] myArray) {
   for (Strins s: myArray) {
      if (s.equals(objective)) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Another way:

```
public static boolean exists (String objective, String[] myArray) {
   for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i].equals(objective)) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

This will return true if `objective` is stored in your array, false in another case.